# Upload image to database Undefined index

Tags: php, mysql

I made theform working with storing the images directly on database and now, I want to learn how to store them in a folder, and store in database just the path.

At this moment I get this error `Notice: Undefined index: uploaded_file in` and I really don't understand why. Please, some F1 :)
Html form:

```
<form action="ad_cont.php" method="POST" class="add_contact" name="add_contact" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file" multiple required> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload"  class="button">  
</form>
```

Php script:

```
$img_path = "images/avatar";
$img_path = $img_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $img_path)) {
   mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `uploads` (filename,path)
   VALUES ('".$_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']."','".$img_path."')");
```

Comment: Missing enctype.

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to your form for file uploads to work.

```
<form action="ad_cont.php" method="POST" class="add_contact" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="add_contact">
<input type="file" name="uploaded_file" multiple required> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload"  class="button">  
</form>
```

The change php code like this.

```
$img_path = "images/avatar";
$img_path = $img_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

$img_name= $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $img_path)) {
   mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `uploads` (filename,path)
   VALUES ('".$img_name."','".$img_path."')");
```

Try changing the code of your form like this and hope it will work then.

Comment: Right, just corrected it but I still get that undefined index there.

Comment: I think it is because you are using $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'] again in the query after moving it. Try storing it in a veriable and use it for db insertion

Comment: @AeJey, there is a syntax error in your <form tag. Please update it

Answer (score 0):

To upload file to server, you need to mention `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in the `<form>`

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ad_cont.php" method="POST" class="add_contact" name="add_contact" >
..
..
</form>
```